# Not understanding jQuery and Server side events

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm having trouble since I'm a jQuery newbie.  Let's assume I have a asp.net application with an ImageButton to save some data.  I want to process this server side code, and if it is successful then I want to animate / toggle a panel that says success or not.

So for instance for an image button I have:

`<asp:ImageButton ID="ibSave" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/save.gif" ToolTip="Save any changes you have made." CausesValidation="False" />`

Now I have server side code that does this:

```
 Protected Sub ibSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ibSave.Click
        'first update the header, then 
        If IsCorrect() Then
            Save()
        Else
            'do not save
        End If
    End Sub
```

After immediately after this lets say if the save executed then I want using jquery to toggle some sort of image / panel that says it was succesful.  If the save didnt happen I want to toggle the panel to say it was not successful.

My issue is how do I call the jQuery function after the server side code has executed?

Comment: this is a long complex answer if you're using webforms

Comment: @Jason - Yes I am using webforms, why would this be so long and complex?

Comment: @Jason - could I do it in another way, have jQuery call the click event (the server side code) of the actual button and then execute the jQuery function on the client side???

Comment: Because with each postback you have to register the javascript script, adding it to the page so it can be displayed.

Comment: He could do it via a callback, but that too is a long answer

Comment: @All - does that mean webforms is a dead end ?  Is it simpler using MVC ?

Comment: @oJM86o, no, webforms is not a dead end. it can be modified to do what you want. please see my answer.

Comment: @Jason this cant be that difficult, I have already done it for various labels like so `$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#lblMessage').fadeOut(10000, function() { 
    });
  $('#lblMessage2').fadeOut(10000, function() { 
    });
  $('#lblMsgStatus').fadeOut(10000, function() { 
    });
   });`

Comment: Adding to the prior comment...so if it was done with labels is it really that much all the more difficult to call a function after a server side image button click ?

Comment: @oJM86o, no the front end part is easy. the hard part is communicating back and forth to the server. however, once you are all set up, it is remarkably easy to maintain and add new methods.

Comment: @oJM86o, Jason is correct, he just worded it oddly in his post initially. Its the whole "I just want to call a server side method in my web form and get the result back via ajax" that is "hard". Its actually not awful though.  This is a pretty popular topic so i'll try and post a comprehensive answer later

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using webforms. If you are, that means you're posting back to the server and refreshing the page each time. This makes it really difficult to render UI effects like jQuery slides and toggles. Your best bet if you want to do something like this is employ WebServices (check around [this blog](http://encosia.com), namely [this article](http://encosia.com/2010/03/03/asmx-and-json-common-mistakes-and-misconceptions/), for how to get this working and some gotchas involved) to leverage AJAX for your backend calls.

Essentially, instead of posting back to the server, you will override the click your user makes with an ajax call to your webservice, posting any data you need. Your webservice then will make any sort of updates required on the backend and then return some data back to the client. From that point, in your "success" callback, you can then make any sort of front end effects happen.

It's kind of convoluted and strange if you're not used to the MVC model, but once you get used to it, you'll find yourself modifying everything to this model.

**EDIT** [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998%28VS.100%29.aspx) may also be of some use.